# CQ5 workflow content inbox | Approve folder content wrong url

Tags: aem, day-cq

We have created a workflow to send approval mail to approver. The payload is jcr:content of a folder or a PDF.
After the coding, the behaviour is for:
A pdf : It generate right URL as http:///damadmin.html#/content/ab/cd/abc.pdf
A folder : It generate the wrong url as http:///damadmin.html#/content/folder-name/jcr:content

So, for folder, we have updated the code to change the payload as the folder-path instead of folder-path/jcr:content
for that we used,

```
WorkflowData wfData = wfSession.newWorkflowData("JCR_PATH", folder_node_path);
    wfSession.updateWorkflowData(workItem.getWorkflow(), wfData);
```

After the code change, 
When a user modify any dam content like a pdf, the url is correct as http:///damadmin.html#/
but when the user modify a folder properties, the mail sent to approver has the wrong url as http:///

means /damadmin.html# is missing.

We need that the correct link should be added for both PDF and Folder.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Issue is resolved.
I am using CQ 5.5.
Sharing my experience.
We don't need to change the payload. The payload can remain as *jcr:content*
We need to do two things:

1. Make sure the *folder-path/jcr:content* has the value in property *jcr:title*. It will be shown in content column of the inbox page.
2. For the folder link in inbox page, it must be as */content//jcr:content*. The problem is because */damadmin.html#* is not added before the url.
   This problem is not coming for any Asset or Page.
   **Solution is:**
   You need add the following code in */libs/cq/workflow/components/inbox/list/json.jsp*

---

A=>
Add private method

```
private String handleDamPathForFolder(Logger log, String payloadUrl, Session session, WorkItem wi)
{
    try
    {
        if(isFolderNode(session, wi))
        {
            return ("/damadmin.html#"+payloadUrl);
        }
    }catch (Exception e)
    {
        log.error("Unable to handle path creation for work item: " + wi.getId(), e);
    }
    return payloadUrl;
}
```

We have to write the method isFolderNode which will return true if the node is a folder.

---

B=>Replace

```
JSONWriterUtil.write(writer, "payload", pathBuilder.getPath(wi),JSONWriterUtil.WriteMode.BOTH, xss);
```

by the follwoing

`JSONWriterUtil.write(writer,"payload",handleDamPathForFolder(log,pathBuilder.getPath(wi), session, wi), JSONWriterUtil.WriteMode.BOTH, xss);`

```
<br/>
```